# echo my sql query in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, delete

here is some minor question but it always bother me while doing the code with magento.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$write = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table = $resource->getTableName('your/model');
```

```
$write->delete(
    $table,
    ['entity_id IN (?)' => [123, 456]]
);
```

```
$write->update(
    $table,
    ['column_1' => 3, 'column_2' => 4],
    ['entity_id = ?' => 123]
);
```

If I use above code to write into DB and I am not sure which query will be formed actually. How would I print the formed SQL through above write object.

I just know this one:

```
echo $collection->getSelect()
```

In which I can get the select query printed on the screen.

Can you please suggest me so that I can get the query which is going to execute or which is executed in last.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

try as below

```
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this is not what I am looking for. I want to print the query which is being executed through **core_write** object

Comment: @MansiRaja give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959307/4349218) a try

Comment: It works.. exactly what I need.. found in log.. thanks buddy :)